# Bring the numpad (and wake up the screen) back in the middle of talk

Tags: nexus-4, screen, touchscreen, 4.4-kitkat

Let's suppose you're talking to someone and need to use keypad.

You take the phone, it turns on the screen, you press something, then you're continuing listening it via the loud speaker.

Then at one moment android dims the screen and then finally turns it off.

Now you're stuck - you cannot press the power (not sure how to call that button) because it would terminate the call. And the screen is not responsive since it turned off.

So how do you deal with it?

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the power button to terminate the call?  If not, you should be able to disable that function in the accessibility settings.

Comment: @Compro01: I do want to leave the behaviour of power button as is.

Comment: What happens if you touch where the home button would be while the screen is off?

Comment: @Compro01: nothing - there is no hardware button and the screen is turned off

Comment: If you're not that concerned about additional power drawn by keeping the display on: you could use e.g. *Tasker* to keep the display always on when a certain app (here: dialer) is in foreground. I'm not sure whether there was a "call connected" trigger as well, so you could use even that.

Comment: @Izzy: so there is no built in way of doing that and everyone suffers from that?! :-S

Comment: No. I never suffer from that. But I never set my power button to end calls (which IMHO is not set so by default). If you use that, and have no other ways of waking the device – well, then there is no other way of waking the device. If you don't want to use a 3rd party app, you might wish to re-think if you really need to end calls using the power button. I don't know of any other solution – but that doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist; I might have missed something. Though in this case, I think that's unlikely.

Comment: @Izzy: "which IMHO is not set so by default" --- the thing is that I've heard about that option from you for the first time and I never changed it since I purchased Nexus 4 :-S Weird. I'm so used to using it already to finish the call :-(

Comment: Have you tried pressing the volume up or down buttons? If no others, your phone must at least have those two hardware buttons.

Comment: Yep, volume buttons change the volume, but don't bring the screen back to life